# Moving project from XIB/NIB to Storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xib

I have a project that I originally started working on in Xcode 4. I then moved this project to Xcode 6. The project compiles and runs swimmingly. I then wanted to move this to use Storyboards.

Reading here and elsewhere I see people say they accomplished this by doing the following:

1. Create storyboard
2. Drag a viewcontroller onto the storyboard
3. Click on the white of the viewcontroller
4. Delete it Goto the original XIB and copy the entire view
5. Paste that into the viewcontroller on the new storyboard
6. Go into the appdelegate.m file and edit the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions section to look like this:

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
       return YES;
   }
   ```

No errors in my code. Builds fine but instead of seeing the new Storyboard / ViewController, I just see a black screen. Im sure I am missing something somewhere but I cannot seem to find what it is.

If you would like to see my code, I have it here: https://github.com/martylavender/LittleToDoApp/tree/Storyboards

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your first view controller as the initial view controller in your storyboard.

[image]

You just need to check the `is initial View Controller` line on the right panel

Comment: I did that but I am still getting a black screen in the simulator.

https://www.evernote.com/l/AJiRJjS3gilDPpwY7fLCH3ZTROVugzsKnDQB/image.png

Comment: Weird, the main interface in your build information is the first think I check opening your project and it was correctly set to your MainStoryboard.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

Looking at the build information of the project, I hadnt set the Main Interface to the MainStoryboard. That with the earlier suggestion fixed it!!
Thanks!!!

Comment: I've done something similar for an OSX app but I the menu buttons are disabled...